display: 'none' and 'block' not working on mobile device (on Shogun)
It functions properly on PC, but for some reason, the filtering doesn't seem to work on mobile devices. I've used 'display: none' and 'block' for this function, and particularly, it's not functioning on mobile. (The ProductContainers exist within Shogun elements.)
<style>
  .product-list {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  .allProductContainerM {
    display: block;
  }

  .accessoriesContainerM,
  .skinAndCoatContainerM,
  .allergyContainerM,
  .jointHealthContainerM {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
.wrap {
  max-width:500px;
  height: 130px;
}
.scroll__wrap {
  overflow-x:auto; 
  white-space:nowrap; 
  font-size:0;
  padding: 15px;
}
.scroll--element {
  display: inline-block; 
  width:100px; 
  height:150px; 
  border-radius:90%; 
  color:white; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size:12px; 
  line-height:100px; 
  text-align:center; 
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
.scroll--element + .scroll--element {
  margin-left:15px;
  
}
.no-scroll {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; 
  scrollbar-width: none; 
}
.no-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; 
}

</style>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="scroll__wrap no-scroll">
    <div class="scroll--element img1 filter-btnM shopallM">Shop All</div>
    <div class="scroll--element img2 filter-btnM jointhealthM">Joint Health</div>
    <div class="scroll--element img3 filter-btnM allergyM">Allergy</div>
    <div class="scroll--element img4 filter-btnM skinandcoatM">Skin and Coat</div>
    <div class="scroll--element img5 filter-btnM accessoriesM">Accessories</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const buttonsM = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-btnM');
        const shopAllBtnM = document.querySelector('.shopallM');
        const jointHealthBtnM = document.querySelector('.jointhealthM');
        const allergyBtnM = document.querySelector('.allergyM');
        const skinAndCoatBtnM = document.querySelector('.skinandcoatM');
        const accessoriesBtnM = document.querySelector('.accessoriesM');

        const allProductContainerM = document.querySelector('.allProductContainerM');
        const jointHealthContainerM = document.querySelector('.jointHealthContainerM');
        const allergyContainerM = document.querySelector('.allergyContainerM');
        const skinAndCoatContainerM = document.querySelector('.skinAndCoatContainerM');
        const accessoriesContainerM = document.querySelector('.accessoriesContainerM');

        function resetButtonStyles() {
            buttonsM.forEach((button) => {
                button.style.borderRadius = '';
                button.style.boxShadow = '';
            });
        }

        //shop all
        function shopAllFilterM() {
            allProductContainerM.style.display = '';
            jointHealthContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            allergyContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            skinAndCoatContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            accessoriesContainerM.style.display = 'none';
  
            resetButtonStyles();
            shopAllBtnM.style.borderRadius = '90em';
            shopAllBtnM.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 0px 6px #F37F20';
        }

        shopAllBtnM.addEventListener('click', function () {
            shopAllFilterM();
        });

        //joint health
        function jointHealthFilterM() {
            jointHealthContainerM.style.display = '';
            allProductContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            allergyContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            skinAndCoatContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            accessoriesContainerM.style.display = 'none';

            resetButtonStyles();
            jointHealthBtnM.style.borderRadius = '90em';
            jointHealthBtnM.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 0px 6px #F37F20';
        }

        jointHealthBtnM.addEventListener('click', function () {
            jointHealthFilterM();
        });

        //allergy
        function allergyFilterM() {
            allergyContainerM.style.display = '';
            allProductContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            jointHealthContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            skinAndCoatContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            accessoriesContainerM.style.display = 'none';

            resetButtonStyles();
            allergyBtnM.style.borderRadius = '90em';
            allergyBtnM.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 0px 6px #F37F20';
        }

        allergyBtnM.addEventListener('click', function () {
            allergyFilterM();
        });

        //skin and coat
        function skinAndCoatFilterM() {
            skinAndCoatContainerM.style.display = ''; 
            allProductContainerM.style.display = 'none'; 
            jointHealthContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            allergyContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            accessoriesContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            
            resetButtonStyles();
            skinAndCoatBtnM.style.borderRadius = '90em';
            skinAndCoatBtnM.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 0px 6px #F37F20';
        }

        skinAndCoatBtnM.addEventListener('click', function () {
            skinAndCoatFilterM();
        });

        //accessories
        function accessoriesFilterM() {
            accessoriesContainerM.style.display = '';
            allProductContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            jointHealthContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            allergyContainerM.style.display = 'none';
            skinAndCoatContainerM.style.display = 'none';

            resetButtonStyles();
            accessoriesBtnM.style.borderRadius = '90em';
            accessoriesBtnM.style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 0px 6px #F37F20';
        }

        accessoriesBtnM.addEventListener('click', function () {
            accessoriesFilterM();
        });
    });
</script>

I also tried using visibility, and it did work; however, the spaces were not removed even after setting width: 0 and height: 0.
